# Salvar 1 documento .pdf a cada 4 paginas do Word

Tags: excel-vba

eu tenho um arquivo do word e preciso que a cada 4 paginas desse word, seja criado 1 pdf em alguma diretorio por meio do VBA. Ou seja, num clique seja criado varios PDF's a cada 4 paginas do meu word.

Procurei em todos os cantos da web e nao achei em lugar algum. Alguem poderia me ajudar por gentileza?

obg!

Tenho esse codigo, porem ele nao esta atendendo minhas necessidades:

Dim StartNum, EndNum As Long
Dim FldName, FleName As String

```
StartNum = 1
EndNum = 4
FldName = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & Application.PathSeparator
FleName = "SectionPdfTest"

For StartNum = 1 To EndNum
  ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=FldName & FleName, _
ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, _
Range:=wdExportFromTo, From:=StartNum, to:=EndNum, UseISO19005_1:=False, _
Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, DocStructureTags:=True, _
CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, BitmapMissingFonts:=True
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: olá, sim podemos ajudar, coloque na pergunta o codigo vba que já tem

Comment: Obrigado @Ricardo! Coloquei o codigo que tenho, no entanto ele nao esta salvando um arquivo novo a cada 4 paginas do word. :(